# Push facebook images to ASP.net website?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

Does anyone know if it is possible to develop a facebook application which could detect images uploaded into a specific album and somehow upload them to an asp.net website automatically?

Any input would be much appreciated as I don't have any experience of FB development yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of an application existing already to accomplish this, however; it is very possible to develop an app to do this.  The reasonable steps may be as follows:

1. Retrieve data (to database) from album for current images
2. Poll the album at a certain interval to check for changes
3. If change exists, compare the album contents with the saved data
4. Download (to the desired location) the images that did not exist already
5. Update application records (database) to reflect the new items

repeat.

This could be produced rather quickly if desired for personal use, and you dont need the finishing touches that an application for general consumption may need.

If this is the route you decide to take, the FB api [Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com) reference is very complete, as well as the information available at stackoverflow.